# Why does calm4.ogg never play even if it is stored in the music folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I am trying to get a removed track called Calm4 (calm4.ogg) to play in game since any music file under `.minecraft/resources/music` will play, and that is where I put the file. Because a track is randomly selected, I removed all other music in that folder and the `newmusic` folder just so that only Calm4 would play.

After loading a world, I am still hearing other tracks including those I have removed from the folders. Am I misunderstanding something, or will Calm4 never play in newer versions of the game?

Comment: It might be a record-only track (a track assigned to an in-game 'record' item that you play with a record player). I can't check at the moment but it's worth looking into

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `.minecraft/resources` folder is not used, so any changes you make there will not affect the game. The folder you'll want is `.minecraft/assets`, but it will probably be easier to just create a [resource pack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Resource_pack).

For example, the following `.minecraft/resourcepacks/NAME/assets/minecraft/sounds.json` would add calm4 to the available music to be played.

```
{
    "music.game": {
        "category": "music",
        "sounds": [
            {
                "name": "music/game/calm4",
                "stream": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You'd place calm4.ogg at `.minecraft/resourcepacks/NAME/assets/minecraft/sounds/music/game/calm4.ogg` within the same resource pack.

You'll still need a `pack.meta` file to define the pack, appearing at `.minecraft/resourcepacks/NAME/pack.meta`. Example content of that file:

```
{
    "pack": {
        "pack_format": 1,
        "description": "Adds calm4.ogg"
    }
}
```

You can find more information regarding `sounds.json` [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json).

Comment: Having the resource pack enabled, I can manually play Calm4 using `/playsound music.game.calm4 @a`, but I’m not sure how I would add it as randomly-playing BGM.

Comment: @GhostCoder20 What Minecraft version are you using? In 1.8.8, your command will not play calm4 with the example I've provided. The example I provided does add calm4 to the randomly-playing background music (both naturally-occurring and via `/playsound music.game @a`).

Comment: I finally got Calm4 to play naturally in 1.8.8. Until then, I repeatedly switched between survival and creative mode and waited for a while before switching. It took some patience, but it works! Thank you!